(Basis Representation) How to Prove $b_k(n)\leq b_k(n-1)$?
NOTE: THIS QUESTION IS NOT A DUPLICATE! THE ANSWER IS NOT IN THE RECOMMENDED QUESTION LINKED TO THIS POST
Reason: While the recommended question does mention $b_k(n)$, it never addressee why $b_k(n)\leq b_k(n-1)$, it instead glosses over this step and asks about a later step in the proof (why $b_k(n)=1$, a result, in which the answer to my question is necessary to conclude.)
I've been trying to prove the basis representation theorem:
$\forall k>1\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^+\exists!a\exists s(a:\downarrow s\to\underline{\downarrow}k\land a_s\neq 0\land n=\sum_{i=0}^sa_ik^i)$
Note: $\downarrow s=\{x\in\mathbb{N}|n\leq s\}$ and $\underline{\downarrow}k=\{x\in\mathbb{N}|n<s\}$
I've searched online and the same proof seems to be used everywhere for this.
Summary of my Work
First I assumed an arbitrary $n$ has a representation $a$ with domain $\downarrow s$
$$\exists s\exists a:\downarrow s\to\underline{\downarrow}k(a_s\neq 0\land n=\sum_{i=0}^sa_ik^i)$$
Next, since $\geq$ well-orders $N$, and $a_s\neq 0$, there must be a maximum number $t$ that doesn't map to $0$.
$$\exists t\leq s(a_t\neq 0\land\forall x\leq t(a_x=0))$$
From there I split the sum :
$$n=\sum_{i=t+1}^s a_ik^i+a_tk^t$$
I ended up with:
$$n-1=\sum_{i=t+1}^sa_ik^i+(a_t-1)k^t+\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}(k-1)k^i$$
I next defined a new sequence $a'$ for $n-1$ so that:
$x<t\implies a'(x)=(k-1)$
$x=t\implies a'(x)=k$
$x>t\implies a'(x)=a(x)$
Thus ...
$$n-1=\sum_{i=t+1}^sa'_ik^i+(a'_t)k^t+\sum_{i=0}^{t-1}a'_ik^i$$
$$n-1=\sum_{i=0}^sa'_ik^i$$
The following three cases complete the representation of $n-1$
$t<s\implies a'_s=a_s\neq 0$
$t=s\land a_t>1\implies a'_s=a_t-1\neq 0$
$t=s\land a_t=1\implies a'_{t-1}=k-1\neq 0$
So that any $n$ having a representation always implies $n-1$ has a representation:
$$\exists s\exists a:\downarrow s\to\underline{\downarrow}k(a_s\neq 0\land n=\sum_{i=0}^sa_ik^i)$$
$$\implies$$
$$\exists s\exists a:\downarrow s\to\underline{\downarrow}k(a_s\neq 0\land n-1=\sum_{i=0}^sa_ik^i)$$
The Problem: Uniqueness
The next part of every proof I've seen on this theorem is that the above would imply that the number of representations of $n$ is always less than or equal to $n-1$
$$b_k(n)\leq b_k(n-1)$$
Without explanation this seems like a HUGE jump in logic.
Let's say there are two representations of $n$, let's call them $r_1n$ and $r_2n$.
How can we be sure that they lead to DIFFERENT representations of $n-1$?
If we can't be sure of that then how can we deny that:
$$b_k(n)>b_k(n-1)$$
?

Alternatively uniqueness follows very simply from a slight generalization of the Rational Root Test.

I haven't examined your posted question, in detail.  Therefore, I have no way of knowing whether the linked question is in fact not a duplicate.  The point of this comment is to advise you, going forward on your future MathSE posted questions, how to best handle such situations.  MathSE reviewers, who are inundated with low-quality posted questions (re MathSE protocol), will occasionally inaccurately label a question as a duplicate.  Once this is done, in my experience, the reviewers will (in general) emotionally dig their heels in.  Once this happens, it is game over. see next comment

Your best defense to avoid this problem is to be pro-active.  Search on MathSE for questions that might plausibly be (incorrectly) linked as a duplicate of your question.  Assuming that they are not duplicates, pick out 1 or 2 of these (false) duplicates, provide their link directly in your posted question, and explain very carefully, why each supposed duplicate is not a duplicate.  ...see next comment

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.  Note that the defensive strategy discussed in my previous comment is also described in the protocol article.
